# Rx-Java Retrofit not getting any response

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to do a sample Rxjava-Retrofit App. I have an API which fetches the weather information of a user entered location from [OpenWeatherMap](http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=11111111111)

My retrofit Api Interface looks like this

```
public interface ApiInterface {
   @GET("data/2.5/weather?appid=11111111111")
   Observable<WeatherData> getWeather(@Query("q") String place);
 }
```

User has to type the place name in the edit text , based on the entered place name I will call the API. Here's  my whole code

```
BehaviorSubject<String> mStringSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

When the user type something

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mStringSubject.onNext(newText);
    return true;
}
```

and then

```
 mStringSubject
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnNext(s -> Log.d(TAG, s))
            .flatMap(s -> mApiInterface.getWeather(s))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> null)
            .subscribe(new Observer<WeatherData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe: ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull WeatherData weatherData) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + weatherData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                }
            });
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? For some reason, it's not displaying anything in the Log. Am I doing something wrong?

Note: when I do

```
 mStringSubject
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(s -> Log.d(TAG, s));
```

Its properly printing the user input values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First move out of main thread and make service call on IO thread.

```
mStringSubject
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
            .doOnNext(s -> Log.d(TAG, s))
            .flatMap(s -> mApiInterface.getWeather(s))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```